# matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow has thinned out tail

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I execute this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.xlim(-3, 3); plt.ylim(-3,3); 
plt.arrow(0,0, 2, 2, head_length=1.4, head_width=1.8, width=1.4,
   alpha=0.2, length_includes_head=True, fc='r')
```

I get the following output:

[image]

However I don't want the tail to be shrunk. On my other computer I don't have this problem. Does anybody know how to solve it?

My matplotlib version is 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be some kind of bug in the `arrow`. You would expect there to be a `tail_width` argument which sets the width of the arrow (or its tail). This however does not exist.

As a workaround, you may use a `FancyArrowPatch` which you need to manually add to the axes. The `FancyArrowPatch` has an argument `arrowstyle` to which you can supply a string of arguments. Within this string `"tail_width"` is correctly recognized.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.xlim(-3, 3); plt.ylim(-3,3);

style="Simple,head_length=28,head_width=36,tail_width=20"
plt.gca().add_patch(
        patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (2,2),arrowstyle=style,alpha=0.2,fc='r' ))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Looking at github bug reports, it seems that pyplot.arrow has multiple problems. I will use the patches.FancyArrowPatch from now on - which works on my matplotlib version just fine using your code.

Comment: What is the unit of `tail_width` argument? Can I customize the unit into something else, just like `ax.transData`?