# mpatches.FancyArrowPatch is too short

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to use `mpatches.FancyArrowPatch` to plot a lot of paths (hundreds in a single plot). I used to use `plt.arrow`, but it makes the plot windows way slow and also takes longer than the patches approach.

Anyway, When I started using `mpatches.Arrow` I got good results for large scales, but scaling down the arrow sizes [leads to a weird bug were the tail becomes triangular.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586086/matplotlib-patches-fancyarrow-has-thinned-out-tail/43588158). That's why I am using `FancyArrowPatch` now, which scales very well thanks to the `dpi_corr` kwarg.

But now take a look at the picture: The bottom arrow is a `mpatches.Arrow` and the top one is a `mpatches.FancyArrowPatch` and the red crosses mark start and end of the arrows. The top one is *way* too short! What's happening here? How can I make it the correct size?

Additional info: In my main program I have large lists containing start and end coordinates. From those I create arrows in a `for` loop using the function(s) you see below. I am using `python 3.4` and `matplotlib 2.0.2`.

[image: fancyarrowpatch plot]

Here is my MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

start1 = [1, 1]
end1 = [3, 3]
start2 = [1, 3]
end2 = [3, 5]

def patchArrow(A, B):
    arrow = mpatches.Arrow(A[0], A[1], B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1])
    return arrow

def patchFancyArrow(A, B):
    arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((A[0], A[1]), (B[0], B[1]))
    return arrow

patches = []
patches.append(patchArrow(start1, end1))
patches.append(patchFancyArrow(start2, end2))
collection = PatchCollection(patches)
plt.plot([1, 3, 1, 3], [1, 3, 3, 5], "rx", markersize=15)
plt.gca().add_collection(collection)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just add the arrow as a patch, everything works as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

style="Simple,head_length=28,head_width=36,tail_width=20"
arrow = arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((1,1), (3,3), arrowstyle=style)
plt.gca().add_patch(arrow)

plt.plot([1, 3], [1,3], "rx", markersize=15)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case you need a collection to add the arrow to, it might be enough to set the `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` arguments to 0.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection


arrow = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((1,1), (3,3),  shrinkA=0,  shrinkB=0)
collection = PatchCollection([arrow])
plt.gca().add_collection(collection)

plt.plot([1, 3], [1,3], "rx", markersize=15)
plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: While your solution does solve the arrow length problem, it remarkably slows down the plotting in my large script and makes it next to impossible to look at my results in detail. [Here is a link to a small section of my large problem](https://i.imgur.com/iZaZbBH.png).

Comment: Looking at that image, why do you need arrows at all?

Comment: The direction of the lines is supposed to change every other line and then rotate every other layer. I have to check that somehow, and I figured that was a good visualization. I guess another approach would be plotting lines and plotting extra arrowheads as regular scatter plot.

Comment: I see the point. I would guess that you don't want to use a FancyArrowPatch anyways because it would not scale when zooming, right?

Comment: Yes this is a problem I am having. Do you have a better solution by chance? I am struggling, because my array comes from an image with around 1000x1000 pixels but gets scaled down to [-1;1].

Comment: I added another solution, does this help you? Because only the arrow's path is added to the colleciton, it should zoom well then.

Comment: Dude, that's it! `shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0` did it! Many many thanks.

Comment: Great. I should have thought about that earlier, but it only came to my mind once I though more about the picture you added.