# PatchCollection draws an over-scaled arrow patch

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's draw an arrow between two scatter points using a FancyArrowPatch:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

points = ax.scatter([0,1],[0,1], marker='o', s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=20)
ax.add_patch(arrow)

fig.show()
```

Looks OK

[image]

Now, let's do the same plot but using a PatchCollection

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

points = ax.scatter([0,1],[0,1], marker='o', s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=20)
col = mpl.collections.PatchCollection([arrow])
ax.add_collection(col)
fig.show()
```

Could someone clarify what's happening?
[image]

Comment: looks like this is a known issue (and has been for some time): https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2341

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44674780/588071) suggests using `shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0`, but that didn't work for me in your case.

Answer (score 1):

The `FancyArrowPatch` has mainly been designed for use with annotations. There is a clear lack of compatibility with other patches and hence a PatchCollection. (As is well pointed out by @tom in the comments, linking to [this issue]).

A workaround could be to create a new patch from the path of the arrow and add that new patch to the collection. This does not allow to keep all functionality of the `FancyArrowPatch` so it is questionable at the end whether not using a PatchCollection at all would not be a better solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

fig, ax  = plt.subplots()

points = ax.scatter([0,1],[0,1], marker='o', s=300)
arrow1 = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0), (1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=50)
arrow2 = mpatches.FancyArrowPatch((.7,0), (0.1,0), arrowstyle='->', mutation_scale=30)

def arrows2collection(ax, arrows,**kw):
    p = []
    for arrow in arrows:
        ax.add_patch(arrow)
        path = arrow.get_path()
        p.append(mpatches.PathPatch(path,**kw))
        arrow.remove()
    col = mpl.collections.PatchCollection(p,match_original=True)
    ax.add_collection(col)
    return col


col = arrows2collection(ax, [arrow1,arrow2], linewidth=1)


plt.show()
```

Comment: +1 for the clever hack, although the question was answered by @tom comment. The sought solution (use of `FancyArrowPatch`) is not possible until bug is fixed.