# Inconsistent/unexpected behavior of FancyArrowPatch in collections

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I define a FancyArrowPatch, the behavior is very different between plotting them individually (with ax.add_patch) vs first adding them to collection (PatchCollection) and subsequently plotting the collection (ax.add_collection):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

style = "Simple, tail_width=0.5, head_width=4, head_length=8"
connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-.2"

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
arrow1 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0.5),(100,0.5),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
arrow2 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((50,0),(50,1),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
arrow3 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0),(100,1),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)

ax.add_patch(arrow1)
ax.add_patch(arrow2)
ax.add_patch(arrow3)
plt.ylim([-.5,1.5])
plt.xlim([-5,105])
plt.title('Plotted individually')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
arrow1 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0.5),(100,0.5),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
arrow2 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((50,0),(50,1),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
arrow3 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0),(100,1),arrowstyle=style,connectionstyle=connectionstyle)

collection=PatchCollection([arrow1,arrow2,arrow3], match_original=True)

ax.add_collection(collection)
plt.ylim([-.5,1.5])
plt.xlim([-5,105])
plt.title('Plotted collectively')
```

[image]

[image]

Since the arrows are defined in the exact same way, I would expect that the plots would also be identical.
While the start and stop coordinates are still correct, basically all other visual parameters are way off. Tweaking the style properties for the second plot also only goes so far in equalizing everything. There seem to be some problems with the kind of coordinate system that the collection is using. I've tried messing around with things like transform or bbox, but to no avail.

The main reason for using a collection here would be performance. I would like to be able to quickly toggle the visibility of a bunch (dozens/hundreds) of arrows simultaneously.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408540/matplotlib-patchcollection-draws-an-over-scaled-arrow-patch) can help ?